# How to enable full logging in KingbaseES database?

Tags: logging

Full logging, also known as verbose logging, is a logging mechanism that captures detailed information about all activities and events occurring within a system or application.
But "sys_log" only record error information and can’t record successful sql statements. If I want to view the specific sql statements executed during an operation, I need to enable full logging. So, How to enable full logging in KingbaseES database?

Answer (score 0):

1.First open the kingbase.conf configuration file in the data directory.

```
vi kingbase.conf
```

2.Look for log_statement

```
/log_statement
```

3.Set log_statement = 'all'

```
#log_statement = 'all'
```

4.After setting up, restart the service.

```
Sys_ctl –D ../../data restart
```

5.You can print logs in real time and perform corresponding operations on the tool

```
tailf kingbase-2021-09-07_001246.log
```